# Let $f(x),g(x),h(x)$ are three differentiable functions satisfying:

Tags: calculus, functions, multinomial-theorem

> Let $f(x),g(x),h(x)$ are three differentiable functions satisfying:
>   
>  $\int (f(x)+g(x))dx=\frac{x^3}3+C_1, \int(f(x)-g(x))dx=x^2-\frac{x^3}{3}+C_2$, $\int\frac{f(x)}{h(x)}dx=-\frac1x+C_3$.
>   
>   $(1)$ The value of $\int (f(x)+g(x)+h(x))dx$ is equal to-
>   
> $(2)$ Number of points of non differentiability of function $\phi(x)=\min\{f(x),f(x)+g(x),h(x)\}$ is equal to-
>   
>   $(3)$ If number of distinct terms in the expansion of $((1+f(x))+(\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{h(x)}))^{\sum n}$, ($n\in N$) is $31$, then the value of $n$ is-

We get by differentiating first and second equations, $f(x)+g(x)=x^2\tag1$$f(x)-g(x)=2x-x^2\tag2$
So $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2-x$. And by a similar argument, $h(x)=x^3$. So answer to the first question is $\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4}+C$. 
For the second one $\phi(x)=\min\{x,x^2,x^3\}$ and all of these are differentiable at every point, and thus, answer to the second question is $0$. 
For the third one, the expression becomes $(1+x+\frac1x)^{\sum n}$, but here is where I got stuck, so how to solve this. And are my previous answers correct?

Comment: both x,-x are differentiable, but $\min \{x,-x\}=-|x|$ is not differentiable at zero.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand. How to evaluate a $\min$ function? @Prometheus.

Comment: When you take the minimum (or maximum) of continuous functions it remains continuous. The problem is that there are gluing points (where to the right the minimum is one function and to the left the minimum is another function), and then it is differentiable there if and only if both of these functions are differentiable and have the same derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part, $x=-1,0,1$ are not differentiable as the limit from left and right are not equal.

For the third part, you have $x^0,x^{\pm1},x^{\pm2},...,x^{\pm15}$ so $\Sigma  n=15\implies n=5$.

Comment: Firstly,can you elaborate more on the second part and I didn't quite understand the meaning of $\sum n$, can you please tell what is meant by it?

Comment: Yes, I would assume it mean $1+2+3+...+n$ and the formula is ${n(n+1)\over 2}$

Comment: I know the formula, but I was asking how did you calculate $n$? What do you mean by those $x$ terms?

Comment: ${n(n+1)\over 2}=15$ and you can solve for $n$, it is a quadratic formula. For the $x$ terms, they mean every term from $x^0$ to $x^{15}$ are obtainable by products of $1,x,{1\over x}$ and furthermore they must all have positive coefficients. $15$ comes from solving $1+2k=31$ where $k$ is the highest degree term.

Comment: And how can you explain the second part?

Comment: Just calculate the left and right limits, for example at $x=-1$, since $min(x,x^2,x^3)=x^3$ when $x<-1$ the left limit is $\lim_{h\rightarrow0-}{(-1+h)^3-(-1)^3\over h}=3$ and since $min(x,x^2,x^3)=x$ when $0>x>-1$ right limit is $\lim_{h\rightarrow0+}{(-1+h)-(-1)\over h}=1$